# Accessing stateless session bean from a main class with in the same package

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, ibm-was

I am having some issue accessing stateless session bean properties. These are the things I have tried so far. Please shed some light what I am missing.

I have name space binding in the IBM WAS 8.5 as global/env

the I have my ejb as :

```
@Singleton 
@Stateless(mappedName="envEJB")
@LocalBean
@ConcurrencyManagement
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class EnvEJB {

    @Resource(lookup="global/env")
    protected String env;


    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    @AccessTimeout(1000)
    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }
```

And I am trying to access on my main class as:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2890");

String str = "java:comp/env/envEJB";
Context context = new InitialContext(env);
EnvironmentEJB ejb = (EnvironmentEJB) context.lookup(str);
```

Only thing I am trying to achieve here is trying to access some name space binding from the server.

Doing above call I am getting

```
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Name space accessor for the java: name space has not been set. Possible cause is that the user is specifying a java: URL name in a JNDI Context method call but is not running in a J2EE client or server environment.
```

Calling as `String str = "java:app/appname/envEJB";` gives me the same error.

**UPDATE**

While doing as

```
Hashtable<String, String> pdEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2890");
Context context = new InitialContext(pdEnv);        
java.lang.Object ejbBusIntf = context.lookup("com.test.EnvironmentEJBRemote");        
EnvironmentEJB ejb = (EnvironmentEJB)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbBusIntf, EnvironmentEJB.class);
```

the following exception occurs

```
Exception in thread "P=925268:O=0:CT" java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot cast class org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub to class com.test.EnvironmentEJB
at com.ibm.rmi.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:396)
at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:148)
at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:43)
```

Comment: I just want some variables accessible stored on server.

Comment: yeah it does deploy without errors...

Comment: You have to change your bean to `@Remote`, you cannot use local beans outside of the application.

Answer (score 1):

The `java:` namespace is only supported in a managed environment (application server or application client).  They are not supported in thin clients (standalone Java SE main classes).  For that, you will need to use a non-`java:` name.  See the `CNTR0167I` messages in SystemOut.log to find the non-`java:` bindings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I also tried context.lookup("ejb/ejbname") also but no luck.

Comment: Is `ejb/ejbname` the value printed in the `CNTR0167I` message?  Can you show the output of those messages for the EJB you're trying to lookup?

Comment: EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.test.EnvironmentEJB interface of the envEJB enterprise bean in the Test.war module of the TestEAR application.  The binding location is: ejblocal:TestEAR/Test.war/envEJB#com.test.EnvironmentEJB
2nd: The binding location is: ejblocal:com.test.EnvironmentEJB
3rd:The binding location is: java:global/TestEAR/Test/envEJB!com.test.EnvironmentEJB

Comment: As Gas said in the comments, you have to actually expose a remote interface or else you won't be able to access the EJB remotely.  That means defining a remote interface and adding `@Remote(YourRemoteIntf.class)` to the EJB.  Then, you should have a new `CNTR0167I` message with a remote binding (one that doesn't start with `ejblocal:` or `java:`).

Comment: Now I have it as:ejb/TestEAR/Test.war/envEJB#com.test.EnvironmentEJBRemote and com.test.EnvironmentEJBRemote and java:global/TestEAR/Test/envEJB!com.test.EnvironmentEJBRemote

Comment: I am getting the following error now:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub incompatible with com.test.EnvironmentEJB

Comment: You must use `PortableRemoteObject.narrow(o, EnvironmentEJB.class)`, where `o` is the result of the lookup.

Comment: getting :java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot cast class org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub to class com.test.EnvironmentEJB. I am doing as Hashtable<String, String> pdEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
  pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
  pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2890");
  Context context = new InitialContext(pdEnv); java.lang.Object ejbBusIntf = context.lookup("com.test.EnvironmentEJBRemote");EnvironmentEJB ejb = (EnvironmentEJB)javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbBusIntf, EnvironmentEJB.class);

Comment: @jjsharma Can you update your post with the new code and full stack trace (including all "Caused by") of the ClassCastException you're currently getting?

Comment: Do you have a local _EnvironmentEJB_Stub class (i.e., does `Class.forName("com.test._EnvironmentEJB_Stub")` work)?  If not, you will need to use the createEJBStubs command to generate stubs for your client classpath.

Comment: I followed link : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21393419 to create stubs. Class.for name does print the stub but I keep getting that cannot cast error.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.  You might try opening a PMR with IBM to get more support.